# Python: Cannot print JSON records from large (7gb+) JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am using Python 3.10.5 and Spyder. So I have been trying to convert a large (7gb) JSON file to a CSV format. I eventually want this to work on 1tb+ JSON files (I know...can't be helped), but I have had issues with manipulating the file. In order to preserve memory, I had the idea to stream the JSON records and append them to a CSV file piece by piece. I tried writing from the stream first and when that would not work I tried to simply print out individual JSON records to the console, but nothing happens at all, not even an error. This is my code:

For the CSV conversion:

```
with open(lrg_file, "rb") as f:
    for record in ijson.items(f, "item"):
        row_x = pd.Series(record, index = ['id','type','actor','repo','payload','public','created_at'])
        row_x.to_csv(dump_out, mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

For printing to console:

```
with open(lrg_file, "rb") as f:
    for record in ijson.items(f, "item"):
        obj = json.dumps(record, indent=4)
        print(obj)
```

My code works on smaller files (2-25 MB) but the same code fails on the larger file; it simply runs silently without printing or throwing an error or doing anything at all. I did find that I can use the ijson.parse function and it will print from the larger file, using the following code:

```
with open(lrg_file, "rb") as f:
    parser = ijson.parse(f)
    for record in parser:       
            obj = json.dumps(record, indent=4)
            print(obj)
```

That allows me to see the prefix/event/value trio for each event in the file, but does not make for an efficient means of converting to .CSV. Any explanation for why my larger file just wont work on my CSV conversion code?

Comment: JSON is not the format for large files. It requires a parser that holds state to be read properly, which requires a lot of RAM. JSON Lines where every line is a JSON object on its own it much better for this.

Comment: Can you add the output of printing your larger file with ijson.parse? And also how does your JSON file look like? It could be happening that ijson.items is using a prefix that is not valid in the largest file.

Comment: Isnt "item" on almost every prefix? And yes parse kind of worked but I just dont know why items didnt work on a bigger file when it worked on a smaller file? Also there was no memory error thrown with the big file, there was just no output.